# Checking whether the Daylight Savings Time is in effect

Tags: iphone, ios4, dst

I am working on an US based application.

I want to get the dst as '1' irrespective of whether DST is on / off in US and dst as '0' if timezone is India.

Is there as API available for getting such output?

What I mean is I need to get dst as '1' if that country is in dst zone. And '0' if the country is in non-dst zone.

Comment: Do you want to know if a timezone has DST adjustment or if it is currently active?

Comment: I want to know if a timezone has DST adjustment

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [NSTimeZone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTimeZone) class, which has a `isDaylightSavingTime` property that returns a BOOL whether DST is in effect or not, and the `daylightSavingTimeOffset` property which tells you the current offset. There are some other methods in that class that you might find useful.

**Edited to add**

I did say there were more methods you might find useful. One is `nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition` which returns the date of the next transition. You could check to see if there is a valid future date for this transition, which will be the case for timezones where there is DST, and an invalid date for timezones where there is no DST.

Comment: Actually i want to know if a perticular timezone has DST adjustment or not.the isdaylightsavingtime property returns yes or no according to the timezone but what i want is that perticular timezone has ever had dst adjustment or not.i.e it should return me dst as '1' for usa throughtout the year not necessary if dst is on or off.